# OpenFlow rules based on a packet size

Tags: sdn, openflow, network-traffic

I am unfamiliar with OpenFlow so have been doing some reading to try and understand if it can solve a problem I have. I want to apply traffic routing of API service requests based on the HTTP header packet size (it is possible to distinguish between services based on this). I have read over some guides on applying packet forwarding and I can't seem to find an answer as to whether this is possible.

Is anyone able to suggest whether this could be possible?

I have read the guidance on packet matching and the only viable field I can see is the packet metadata.